# Make a view fall of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a `RelativeLayout` where I add and position `Views` (`Buttons`, `TextViews`) by changing their top and left margins. I can position them half outside the layout on the top and left side, but when I try to move them half outside the layout on the bottom or right side, they change shape to stay inside the layout.

**How can I make the views fall outside the screen instead of resize them self?**

Giving them a width does not solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it using `RelativeLayout`, which always need to fit the screen size.

You can use `ScrollView` wich extends a `FrameLayout` and can be larger then the screen.

Regards.